# Which is more efficient in this scenario: std::vector<bool> or std::unordered_map<int>?

Tags: c++

I know a classic programming interview question is "*Given an array of N-1 integers which are numbers 1 through N with one of them missing, find the missing number*." I'm thinking that

```
int missing_number ( int * arr, int n )
{
    std::vector<bool> booVec(n, false);
    int * offArrEnd = arr + n;
    while (arr != offArrEnd) booVec[*arr++] = true;
    return std::find_first_of(booVec.begin(), booVec.end(), false)
        - booVec.begin() + 1;       
}
```

would be a good solution since instantiating a `vector<bool>` element to all `false` will take a short amount of time, and so will modifying its elements via `booVec[*arr++]`. I know I could save 1 operation by changing it to

```
int missing_number ( int * arr, int n )
{
    std::vector<bool> booVec(n, false);
    int * offArrEnd = arr + n;
    while (arr != offArrEnd) booVec[*arr++] = true;
    std::vector<bool>::iterator offBooEnd = booVec.end();
    return std::find_first_of(booVec.begin(), offBooEnd, false)
        - offBooEnd + 1;       
}
```

But I'm wondering if using a similar procedure with `unordered_map` might be faster overall? I presume it would take longer to instantiate every member of an `unordered_map`, but it might take faster to modify its elements.

Comment: `bool * offBooEnd = booVec.end();` [won't even compile](http://ideone.com/rOBgdv), because `std::vector<bool>` is specialized to use bitfields to store the elements.

Comment: @cdhowie: my bad. need to make an edit.

Comment: Not sure your code is valid even after the edit. Is `vector<bool>::iterator` guaranteed to be RandomAccess? You can't add and subtract them otherwise. Use `std::distance`, or better yet, use `vector<char>`.

Comment: Why not simply sum all the numbers? The sum of the first `n` integers is `n(n+1)/2`, sum the numbers in your array and call that `s`. Then `n(n+1)/2 - s` is the missing number. That would be waay faster than allocating `n` elements in any collection.

Comment: And define *optimal*. Even if you manage to reduce algorithmic complexity by using some container fancier than `vector`, it might be difficult to beat `vector`'s runtime performance for most reasonable values of `N`.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff: Ah, I bet that's the answer the interviewer was looking for :)

Comment: Since you have both algorithms, the only real answer is to profile.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you used above is the basis of [Pigeonhole-Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort), with an additional guarantee of no duplicates making it even more efficient.
Thus, the algorithm is O(n) (tight bound).

A `std::unordered_set` has O(1) expected and O(n) worst case complexity for each of the N-1 insertions though, for a total of O(n) expected and O(n*n) worst case.
Even though the complexity in the expected (and best) case is equal, `std::unordered_set` is a far more complex container and thus looses the race in any case.

`std::vector<bool>` does not contain any `bool`, but is a specialization using proxies to save space (Widely regarded as a design-failure)!
Thus, using a different instantiation of `vector`, with `char` or even `int` will consume more modifiable memory, but might due to more efficient code (no bit-twiddling) be more efficient.

**Anyway, both implementations efficiency is dwarfed by simply adding the elements and subtracting the sum from what it would be for an uninterrupted sequence,** like [Nikola Dimitroff comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684364/which-is-more-efficient-in-this-scenario-stdvectorbool-or-stdunordered-ma#comment41967209_26684364).

```
int missing_number ( int * arr, int n )
{
    unsigned long long r = (unsigned long long)n * (n+1) / 2;
    for(n--)
        r -= arr[n];
    return (int)r;
}
```

Comment: The `unordered_Xxx` containers are average case `O(1)` and worst case `O(n)`, never `O(lg n)`.

Answer (score 1):

`vector` in this case where `n` is bounded should be able to beat `unordered_map`. The underlying data structure for `unordered_map` is essentially a `vector`, where a hash is taken, and the modulus of the hash is taken to choose the index to start at in the `vector`. (The `vector` stores the hash table "buckets") As a result, a plain `vector` is already a perfect hash table and you have a perfect hash -- N from the array! Therefore, the extra mechanism provided by `unordered_map` is going to be overhead you're not using.

(And that's assuming you don't happen to fall into the case where `unordered_map` can have O(n) lookup complexity due to hash collisions)

That said, `vector<char>` may beat `vector<bool>` due to the bitfield behavior of `vector<bool>`.